# Weird behavior of webView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I've got an app with a webview.  It was working great, and then I moved the webView into an NSSplitView.  Now it seems for some reason that whenever I press any key to enter text into the webview, it scrolls down.  I haven't a clue as to what could cause this.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... the webview was a pixel or so outside the bounds of the view it was inside of.  I haven't any idea why that caused what it did, but when I put it back within the view's bounds, the problem went away.  Weird.